# Items and total price not updated in basket php mysql jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, oop

I'm using object oriented programming php and I'm having some issues. The items are correctly added to the cart but when clicking enter or press update button to update the items and the subtotal and total values it doesn't work. 
This is my basket page:

```
    <?php  
 $session = session::getSession('basket');

$objBasket = new basket();

$out = array();

if(!empty($session)){
$objCatalogue = new catalogue();
foreach($session as $key => $value) {
    $out[$key] = $objCatalogue->getProduct($key);

  }
}
require_once('_header.php');
?>

<div class="container">
<ol class="breadcrumb" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="category.html">Fiction</a></li>
<li class="active">Shopping Cart</li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="container"> 
  <?php if (!empty($out)) { ?> 
 <div class="col-md-12" id="big_basket">
   <div class="box">
       <h2>Shopping cart</h2>

         <div class="table-responsive">

            <form action="" method="post" id="frm_basket">
              <table class="table">
               <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>E-book</th>
                 <th>Quantity</th>
                 <th>Price</th>
                 <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <?php foreach($out as $item){ ?>
               <tbody>
                <tr>
                 <td><?php echo      helper::encodeHTML($item['ebook_title']); ?></td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="qty-<?php echo $item['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $session[$item['id']]['qty']; ?>"  class="fld_qty" /></td>
                 <td>&pound;<?php echo number_format($objBasket->itemTotal($item['price'], $session[$item['id']]['qty']),2); ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo basket::removeButton($item['id']); ?></td>
                </tr>
               </tbody>
               <?php } ?>
               <?php if($objBasket->_sub_total != 0){ ?>
               <tfoot>
                 <tr>
                 <th colspan="2">Subtotal</th>
                 <th>&pound;<?php echo number_format($objBasket->_sub_total,2);?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                <tr>
                 <th colspan="2">Total Price</th>
                 <th><strong>&pound;<?php echo number_format($objBasket->_total,2);?></strong></th>
                </tr>
               </tfoot>

              </table>
           </form>

        </div>

     <!-- /.table-responsive -->
     </div>

     <div class="box-footer">
       <div class="pull-left">
         <a href="category.php" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>Continue shopping</a>
       </div>
       <div class="pull-right">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" class="update_basket"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i>Update</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><a href="./?page=checkout">Checkout<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a></button>
       </div>
     </div>

  </div>
 <?php } else { ?>
  <p>Your shopping cart is currently empty</p>
  <?php } ?>
  </div>

   </div>

</div>



 <?php require_once('_footer.php'); ?>
```

And this is my jquery that should allow to instantly upadate the basket:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){


function refreshBasket(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'mod/basket_view.php',
  dataType:'html',
  success: function(data){
    $('#big_basket').html(data);
    initBinds();
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert('Error occurred');
     }
   });
 }



 if($(".add_to_basket").length > 0){
    $(".add_to_basket").click(function() {

        var trigger = $(this);
        var param = trigger.attr("rel");
        var item = param.split("_");

        $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: 'mod/basket.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data: ({ id : item[0], job : item[1] }),
              success: function(data){
                  var new_id = item[0] + '_' + data.job;
                  if(data.job != item[1]){
                    if(data.job == 0){
                        trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                        trigger.text("Remove from basket");
                        trigger.addClass("red");
                    }else{
                        trigger.attr("rel", new_id);
                        trigger.text("Add to basket");
                        trigger.removeClass("red");
                    }
                  }
              },
               error: function(data){
                alert("Error ocurred");
               }
        });
        return false;
    });
  }


  initBinds();

  function initBinds(){
 if ($('.update_basket').length > 0){
     $('.update_basket').bind('click',updateBasket);
 }
 if ($('.fld_qty').length > 0){
     $('.fld_qty').bind('keypress', function(e){
      var code = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if (code == 13){
        updateBasket();
      }
     });
 }
 }


  function updateBasket(){
   $('#frm_basket : input').each(function(){
  var sid = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
  var val = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'mod/basket_qty.php',
      data: ({ id: sid[1], qty: val}),
      success: function(){
         refreshBasket();
      },
      error: function(){
        alert('Error occurred');
      }
  });
});
}
});
```

Comment: What framework is this? I don't see any direct MySQL calls here.

Comment: @tadman It's just MYSQL OOP. I'm using classes and methods.

Comment: Just seeking to clarify here. It looks like you've rolled your own ORM if that's the case.